# replace current dynamic parameter with routerLink in angular 4

Tags: angular

Say I have a route like this in angular 4:

```
/:study_id/folders/:folder_id
```

I want to create a route that replaces only the `:folder_id`

I have tried this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[folder.id]">a</a>
```

But this appends the folder_id onto the existing route so it becomes

```
/:study_id/folders/:folder_id/:folder_id
```

I want to replace `:folder_id` without having to specify all the other parts of the url.

Comment: Hello. You can pass options into routerLink directive: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras . 

just use "relativeTo" the activated Route of your Folder Component

Comment: this still does appends the folderId `this.router.navigate([`folder.id], { relativeTo: this.route });`

Comment: I'm on angular 4 sadly I don't think this works

Comment: replace this /:study_id/folders/:folder_id with /:study_id/folders/ in route

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options into routerLink directive: angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

In Component:

```
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

          constructor(
            private router:Router,
            public route: ActivatedRoute) {  
          }

          navigate(folder){
            this.router.navigate([folder.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
          }
```

In Markup:

```
<a (click)="navigate(folder)"></a>
```